# Java: Repeated exceptions filtering?

Tags: java, exception

I have a JBoss EAP server on a free hosting, and now and then a situation occurs which makes the app start throwing exceptions with lenghty stack traces on each request.
That causes the logs to reach dozens of MB per day, and after some time, the hosting runs out of disk space.

I'd like to filter the exceptions. Precisely, I want something which would take the exception and tell me if the same exception was already seen or not. Application wide. Could be expiring cache.

*Besides doing it on my own using a map and examinating the exceptions, what are my options?*

I recall I've seen some `RepeatedExceptionsHandler` or something such for Log4j which I use, or maybe it was Hibernate, but can't find it in a quick google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I implemented this simple counter.

```
02:23:18,324 INFO  Characteristic: 46d21ef0{8a5b1c7c@293{b0d929ae@276{b0d929ae@182{de8e612a@241
02:23:18,324 ERROR Error rendering: /programovani/artificial_intelligence/covering_ai_theory.texy: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Definition lists not supported yet.
        at cz.dynawest.jtexy.modules.ListModule$DefListPatternHandler.handle(ListModule.java:293)
        ...
02:23:19,956 INFO  Characteristic: 46d21ef0{8a5b1c7c@293{b0d929ae@276{b0d929ae@182{de8e612a@241
02:23:19,957 ERROR Recurring rendeding error: /programovani/artificial_intelligence/covering_ai_theory.texy
```

Usage:

```
    catch( Exception ex ){
        int count = repeatedExDetector.countException( ex );
        if( count < 2 )
            log.error("Error rendering: " + path, ex);
        else
            log.error("Recurring rendering error: " + path);
        add( new TexyDocumentErrorPanel("document", "Error occured when loading document.", "Couldn't load: " + path, 500));
    }
```

Implementation:

[On my blog](https://community.jboss.org/people/ozizka/blog/2013/07/21/repeated-duplicated-exception-counter-filter).

Answer (score 1):

I, too, have filled my disk with log files, so I feel your pain!  My first instinct was indeed a version of the RollingFileAppender solution, but something that ended up working for me in the long run was to actually offload the problem entirely.  I use a service called [Appygram](http://www.appygram.com) (admittedly, a service I also contribute to) to which you can send your exceptions.  You can format your exception messages however you like, and it has duplicate-detection built-in based on an API key, so you get the application-wide checking.

Personally, I format my exceptions with HTML to make them easier to read because I send a lot of data, but you can send whatever you want.  There's a web interface as well for you to browse through received exceptions, or you can forward them to e-mail or any other web service.

Anyway, if you do something like that, you can keep your logs from filling since the information gets off of your server, and you won't get slaughtered with the same exception repeatedly.  And if you do end up checking out Appygram specifically, let me know, I can point you to some helpful Java libraries to get you started.

Comment: Interesting, indeed! There's a similar service by Red Hat, ABRT, which is now getting support for Java and Java EE as well. https://github.com/jfilak/abrt-java-connector

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RollingFileAppender and configure it properly. You need to give the max file size and the no of files you would like to keep as backup. This won't help you to filter exceptions but it will help you not to go out of disk space.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html

Refer http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html for an example of such a configuration (section under 'RollingFileAppender')

Comment: Thanks, but this solves a different problem. I would still have few pages long stack traces for each request.